# Vb.net Current Date minus Date

Tags: vb.net, winforms, date

lets say that my date is:

```
    Dim theDate As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("2013-04-10 21:34 PM", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

im using this format:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm tt"
```

i want to get the current date and do somthing like:

```
Dim theDate As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("2013-04-10 21:34 PM", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
Dim currentTime As System.DateTime = System.DateTime.Now
dim Result as new datetime
Result = currentTime.Date - theDate
```

Update:

i tried:

```
Dim currentTime As System.DateTime = System.DateTime.Now
Dim date1 As New System.DateTime(2013, 4, 10, 21, 34, 10)
Dim date2 As New System.DateTime(currentTime.Year, currentTime.Month, currentTime.Day, currentTime.Hour, currentTime.Minute, currentTime.Second)
Dim diff1 As System.TimeSpan
diff1 = date2.Subtract(date1)
MsgBox(diff1.ToString)
```

Answer (score 4):

A `TimeSpan` will allow you to subtract dates.

[DateTime.Subtract Method (TimeSpan)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ae6246z1.aspx)

```
Dim date1 As New System.DateTime(1996, 6, 3, 22, 15, 0)
Dim date2 As New System.DateTime(1996, 12, 6, 13, 2, 0)

Dim diff1 As System.TimeSpan
' diff1 gets 185 days, 14 hours, and 47 minutes.
diff1 = date2.Subtract(date1)

MsgBox(diff1.Days)
MsgBox(diff1.Hours)
MsgBox(diff1.Minutes)
```

Here are all the [members of the TimeSpan class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx)

Comment: thank you bro, diff1.XYZ (Years, Months, Days and etc date Range) 'XYZ' is not a member of 'System.TimeSpan'